# My web on iPad, iPhone, iPod

Tags: ios, css, iphone, html, ipad

i'm creating my first web site and it's going great, looks good, and works properly. The problem i have is that i just uploaded the files to the web hosting to see how is it looking across different devices, looks great on my Smart TV, on my Android phone, on the MacBook, BUT on the iPhone and the iPad everything looks bad.

The slider is no longer overflowing, the widht is not working, even the menu buton is gone and the nav is always showing, please i need some help with this, is there some code to add so this can work on IOs movile devices?

I been looking the internet for hours trying to find the solution, i found something that includes this code:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

But nothing happens everything looks bad.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post a link to your site? It will be very difficult to diagnose the issues otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: It looks ok on my iPhone 5, except the expanded nav is too narrow and cuts off “Nosotros.” Can you upload a screenshot of what you’re seeing? Also, what devices are you using and what versions of iOS?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time man! i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using CSS properties that need to be prefixed in order to work in `-webkit` browsers, even in newer versions, such as `display:flex`, `justify-content`, `transition`, `flex-direction`,...

The practical solution is to write normal (up to date) CSS and than run it through a tool that will add the necessary prefixes for making it compatible with most browsers. It's called auto-prefixing and you can read more about it <kbd>[here](https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/)</kbd>. Good auto-prefixing tools are connected to [`caniuse`](http://caniuse.com/) and can be configured for various specific needs (prefix for last three versions from each browser, or prefix for all browsers with an above X usage percentage, or combinations between the two).

Here are the auto-prefixed versions of your project's CSS files. Replace `assets/css/header.css` with:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

header{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "roboto";
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#btn-menu{
    display: none;
}

header label{
    display: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

header label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.menu li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    header label {
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    }

    .menu{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        width: 30%;
        margin-left: -30%;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        }

    .menu ul{
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
    }
    #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu{
        margin: 0;
    }

}
```

And `assets/css/body.css` with:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
body{
    z-index: 500;
    position: relative;
}

#logo{
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

#logo-image{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
}

#containerslider{
    padding-top: 59px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.slider{
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 400%;
}

.slider .section{
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider img{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-prev, .btn-next{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif; "roboto";
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-prev{
    left: 10px;
}

.btn-next{
    right: 10px;
}

.btn-prev:hover, .btn-next:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.space{
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! is working perfect now, i didn't know about the prefixes and now thanks to you i learned something very important. Thanks again for your time! you are the man.

Comment: You're quite welcome, Alvaro. To Stack Overflow, I mean. :)